# SRA to FASTQ file via. Python | URLError

Tags: python, wget, bioinformatics, fastq, ncbi

Update: The subject FTP server has been decommissioned: [Discussion] (https://github.com/ewels/sra-explorer/issues/14)

Could there be an alternative?

I want to download `.sra` files and convert them into `.fastq` files, all through `Python`.

I am running this through `Google Colaboratory`, before implementing into a PyCharm application.

```
import wget
import sys
import os
sra_id = "SRX10360832"
url = 'ftp://ftp-trace.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sra/sra-instant/reads/ByRun/sra/' + sra_id[:3] + '/' + sra_id[:6] + '/' + sra_id + '/' + sra_id + '.sra'
print(url)
print("Downloading... please wait!!")
filename = wget.download(url) # !

if filename:
  print("\nDownload Complete "+ sra_id)
  print("\nConverting...")
  cmd = 'fastq-dump ' + sra_id + '.sra'
  os.system(cmd)
```

On line `filename = wget.download(url)` is where I get the following error:

```
error_perm: 550 sra/sra-instant/reads/ByRun/sra/SRX/SRX103/SRX10360832: No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
URLError: <urlopen error ftp error: error_perm('550 sra/sra-instant/reads/ByRun/sra/SRX/SRX103/SRX10360832: No such file or directory')>
```

Same error occurs when including `.gz` at the end of url.

This is based on a [Git repo](https://gist.github.com/sourabhdattawad/53d765a8c9c72c1c4ec1af56c44e35a7) but uses an old version of Python

---

Importance of this is to download `.sra` files via. `ftp://` and convert them to `.fastq` readable format, without `Linux`. Python doesn't handle raw `.sra` files.

Comment: the url does not point to a file. can you include the full url you are trying to access?

Comment: @jakub I want to download this dataset: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sra/?term=SRX10360832. However, it is only through the 'ftp://' link that you can download the .sra file.

Comment: if you look at the run (https://trace.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Traces/sra/?run=SRR13983333) and click "Data access", there is a link to a fastq file there. does that help?

Comment: This seems to be the correct file: '.sra'. I do still would need this script for downloading this via. 'ftp://' as this would convert it to '.fastq' readable format. Python cannot handle/ open '.sra' files. My reasoning for making this script, and for convenience of only entering the SRA ID to download. @jakub

Comment: Why do you need the SRA? Both `fastq-dump` and `fasterq-dump` directly take just an SRR ID., e.g., `fasterq-dump SRR13983333`. Otherwise, use the `prefetch` command to get the SRA.

Comment: Hi, are these Python commands or linux commands? I was looking to implement a Python only API. However, their FTP server is no longer up :(

Comment: @merv Would it still be possible to make Python only code for download FASTQ files directly? as you were suggesting

Comment: I don't see the motivation: the code shows a dependence on sra-toolkit for dumping from SRA to FASTQ, so why not simply use the already built-in downloading capabilities? What value is supposed to be added?

Comment: I'm developing an application for Biologists with an interest in Bioinformatics; all without requiring any technical intervention. Could you share with me the built-in download capabilities, please? I'm learning as I go @merv